# Understanding primordial Statistical Fluctuations in the Universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, structure-formation

I am trying to answer the question,

> Whether gravitational collapse began from Statistical fluctuations in
> the early Universe?

In order to answer this I must find out the total number of particles in a body of certain mass say $$10^6 M_{\odot}$$

The number of particles is given by $$N_{body} = N \pm \sqrt{N}$$ where $$\sqrt{N}$$ is the number of statistical fluctuations. I am further told that,

$$N_{body} \simeq 10^{63} \pm 3 \times 10^{31}$$

where $$N = 10^{63}$$ from the calculation $$N = Number\ of\ solar\ masses \times Mass\ of\ the\ sun\ in\ gram\ \times Avogadro's\ number$$

I did not understand this last part. How is one gram of sun equal to one mole?

In general, how does mole interact with more standard measures for example kg or grams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did not understand this last part. How is one gram of sun equal to one mole?

Amount of material can be expressed using grams like that :
$$ \text{Moles} = \frac {M_g}{m_a \cdot N_A} $$,
where $M_g$ is mass of matter in grams, $m_a$ is atom mass in grams too, $N_A$ - Avogadro constant.

Knowing that Sun is primary composed of Hydrogen atoms, which has mass of $1.67×10^{−24}~\text{grams}$ ,gives:

$$ \text{Moles} = \frac {1~g} { 1.67×10^{−24} g × N_A} \approx 1~\text{mol} $$

So yes, 1 gram of Hydrogen (Sun) material has about 1 mole substance.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you!!!